How to set up COLUMN HEADING in Oracle SQLcl?
I'm trying to create a series of COLUMNs with HEADING values to generate a report:
SET PAGESIZE 1;
SET LINESIZE 400;
    COLUMN C_DATEOFFSET NEW_VALUE VAL_DATEOFFSET    FORMAT A20  HEADING From_Julian;
    COLUMN C_DATEOFFSE2                             FORMAT A20  HEADING From_Date;
    COLUMN C_GLOBALNAME                             FORMAT A20  HEADING DB_Name;
    COLUMN C_OSUSER                                 FORMAT A20  HEADING OS_User;
    COLUMN C_DBUSER                                 FORMAT A20  HEADING DB_User;
    COLUMN C_TIMESTAMP                              FORMAT A40  HEADING TimeStamp;

ACCEPT MOFFSET DEFAULT '1' PROMPT 'Month Offset: ';

SELECT VARGN C_GLOBALNAME, VAROS C_OSUSER, VARDB C_DBUSER, 
        TO_CHAR(VARTS, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI TZH') C_TIMESTAMP, 
        TO_CHAR(VARDTOFF, 'YYYY-MON-DD') C_DATEOFFSE2, TO_CHAR(VARDTOFF, 'YYYYDDD') - 19E5 C_DATEOFFSET
        FROM (SELECT
            GLOBAL_NAME VARGN, UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER')) VAROS, USER VARDB, SYSTIMESTAMP VARTS,
            TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - INTERVAL '&MOFFSET' MONTH, 'YYYYMM"01"'), 'YYYYMMDD') VARDTOFF
                FROM GLOBAL_NAME);

SET PAGESIZE 0;

My expectation was to get the results like how I see them in SQL Developer:
DB_Name              OS_User              DB_User              TimeStamp                                From_Date                     From Julian
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
JDEPD03              FELIPE.VIDAL         43CY                 2024-SEP-11 16:57 -05                    2024-AUG-01                        124214

But when I turn to SQLcl, it is not working:
C_GLOBALNAME         C_OSUSER             C_DBUSER             C_TIMESTAMP                              C_DATEOFFSE2                 C_DATEOFFSET
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- ---------------------------------------- -------------------- --------------------
JDEPD03              FELIPE.VIDAL         43CY                 2024-SEP-11 17:02 -05                    2024-AUG-01                        124214

Any suggestions on why the Column Headings are not consistent? Any SET parameter that I might be missing?
Thanks!

You should not use SYSDATE - INTERVAL '&MOFFSET' MONTH as it can fail at the end of the month when the previous month has fewer days. Use the ADD_MONTHS function instead. fiddle

You can also use trunc(sysdate, 'MM') to get the first of the current month, and then subtract your offset (with either method) to get your VARDTOFF date value, rather using string conversion. fiddle

The column command works as expected, at least in version 24.1. I wondered if you had set sqlformat ansiconsole but you haven't mentioned it and the output you showed isn't consistent with that. Still, maybe check show sqlformat, or set sqlformat default to rule that out.

Hi, if I'm using SET SQLFORMAT CSV will it have an impact? I'm downloading the full extract in CSV. Can it be a conflict? About the Month, thank you both for the recommendation.

An alternative to using SQL*Plus commands to set the headings is to specify the column aliases in the query:
COLUMN "From_Julian" NEW_VALUE VAL_DATEOFFSET  FORMAT A20;
COLUMN "From_Date"                             FORMAT A20;
COLUMN "DB_Name"                               FORMAT A20;
COLUMN "OS_User"                               FORMAT A20;
COLUMN "DB_User"                               FORMAT A20;

SELECT GLOBAL_NAME AS "DB_Name",
       UPPER(SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV', 'OS_USER')) AS "OS_User",
       USER AS "DB_User",
       TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'YYYY-MON-DD HH24:MI TZH') AS "TimeStamp",
       TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -&MOFFSET),
         'YYYY-MON-DD',
         'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=English'
       ) AS "From_Date",
       TO_CHAR(
         ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MM'), -&MOFFSET),
         'YYYYDDD'
       ) - 1900000 AS "From_Date"
FROM   GLOBAL_NAME;


Can I still use the Column "From_Date" as a variable (with NEW_VALUE)? Thanks,

@FelipeVidal The easiest way to find out is to try it yourself and see. (But, yes, you should be able to.)
